# smalldatetime comparison SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-comparison, smalldatetime

I have a *smalldatetime* field in my SQL database. The SQL format for this is type is : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

I need to query my database and request all records where the date matches today's date AND the time portion is 100 minutes from the present time.

Help with the SQL would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DateField = CONVERT(smalldatetime,dateadd(MINUTE,100,getdate()),120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer didn't work for me, I am including an alternative below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE cast(DateField as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```